# Exporting query results in MySQL Workbench beyond 1000 records

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I'm trying to save a query result of about 1,000,000 records in MySQL Workbench.

When I run the SELECT, only 1000 records shows up (MySQL Workbench's default limit). I know I can change the limit, or remove the limit, but I don't want 1,000,000 records to be loaded into the result panel (which might crash my computer?), but I do want to save the results to a file.

Does MySQL Workbench let you save the results of a query directly to a file? Or save the whole result set instead of the 1,000?

Comment: I could also write a PHP script that does the query, and outputs to CSV, but that might crash my server too, right? If you fopen() to append, will a huge file be problematic?

Comment: I'm not familiar with workbench, but you could write a script to just get 1000 records at a time just setting the offset correctly each time (i.e. firs time `LIMIT 0,1000`, second time `LIMIT 1000,1000`, then `LIMIT 2000,1000`, etc...), appending the results each time to a file. No need to hold the entire million records in memory, or try to write them all at once to the file.

Comment: The other complication is that the query itself does have to refer to other records. It does a SUM() and checks the SUM with a HAVING before the record is allowed to be in the result set. So I do need to process the entire data set first, then output it.

Comment: You can process the entire dataset exactly as you currently do and still apply a LIMIT just for obtaining and outputting the results. The LIMIT will not affect the results in any way at all, it juts limits which set of the results are returned to you.

Comment: If you **create a table containing the results of your select**, then you can use any standard tool or command to transfer the result to a file - even a file on your client workstation. See my answer below for details. [Apologies, I try not to promote my own answers, but this out-of-box thinking is missing from the existing answers.]

Answer (score 55, accepted):

It is possible to change the query result row limit, or remove the limit entirely.

1. Go to **Edit → Preferences → SQL Editor (tab)**. If you can't find **Query Results**, go to **SQL Queries(tab)** instead.
2. Locate the **Query Results** section and untick the **Limit Rows** checkbox
3. Click **OK**.
4. Re-run your query.

Comment: *"I'm trying to save a query result of about 1,000,000 records"* In this case I don't think removing the limit is the right course of action.

Comment: In MySQL Workbench 5.2 they moved the *Limit Rows* option from `SQL Editor` to `SQL Queries` tab.

Comment: `Edit`>`Preferences`>`SQL Editor`>`SQL Execution` on MySQL Workbench 6.3 on Ubuntu Linux

Comment: *This doesn't work*. The box is unticked but a resultset of 2001 rows is still limited to 814 when exported.

Comment: Actually this worked just fine for me without any issues for 17,000 records. I simply unchecked the Limit Rows box as the answer suggests, then I'm able to export them all at once to a file and all 17,000 records are in the file for me.

Answer (score 42):

`LOAD DATA INFILE` has a sibling called [SELECT ... INTO OUTFILE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/select-into.html). You can use it like:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable
INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/mytable.csv'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
    OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

This method will not use unnecessary resources in the UI.

As [@florian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2132691/florian) pointed out: It will, however, create the output file on the database server, not on the client machine.

Also note that security frameworks like **SELinux** or **AppArmor** might prevent MySQL from writing files outside the standard *databases* folder. If you experience *permission denied* errors, even though the directory is writable by the `mysql` user, it is likely be one of these.

Comment: If permission issue , I went with this option https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/cannot-create.html

Comment: Your answer looked really promising, but I've been unable to figure out how to avoid the permissions issues.

Comment: @Ryan check out your MySQL settings, a directory must be defined for temporary tables, that directory will be writable by MySQL https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/temporary-files.html

Answer (score 6):

Just add 'limit $number' append the SQL clause.
if you do not add limit,the default returned lines is 1000.

Comment: This does not answer the question whatsoever

Comment: Works for me, add the limit to a big number and then all rows returned and you can export them.

Comment: This answer is completely irrelevant to the question.

Comment: This is a perfectly relevant answer: invoking LIMIT will override the settings of MySQL Workbench.

Comment: This worked for me, thanks.

Answer (score -1):

There is an option available in MySql to export all the records. Named Query results operations.

[image]

Comment: That does not look like a screenshot taken from MySQL workbench