# Exporting query results of more than 1000 rows

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

This question has already been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10288716/exporting-query-results-in-mysql-workbench-beyond-1000-records)
. But the accepted answer does not really answer the question. I've just started working on MySQL Workbench from Teradata. I used to be able to configure Teradata so that when running queries the limit was defaulted to 2,000 but when I exported results to a file the limit was removed automatically. Is there a way to configure MySQL Workbench in the same way without having to manually change the settings back and forth each time I want to export?

For example, I know that I can go edit > preferences > SQL Queries and then set or remove the default Limit. I know that I can remove it each time I need to export the results.

But is there a setting that removes the limit automatically for exported results?

Or is there a way to export the results within the SELECT query so that the resulting full length .CSV file saves to my Desktop (And not the server, as per the answer I linked to above)?

Comment: You could create a view from your SELECT statement and export this view with MySQL Workbench.

Comment: I could I suppose but that's probably as much work as just changing the limit in the settings

Comment: You could use the button "Toggle limiting of number of rows returned by query" too.

Comment: @VMai yes! Thanks that'll do it. Just saw it now.